# How to send and receive sms between emulators?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to create to different apps that will run on separate emulators, one app will send a sms and the other should receive it. I'm using SmsManager to send and BroadcastReceiver to receive but so far I haven't made the receiving emulator react at all.

My sender seems to work, in that emulator I can see the sent textmessages in the default sms-app. But nothing seems to happen in my receiver, I guess I don't connect them correctly but I don't know how to fix that? I've tried the similar posts I've seen on Stackoverflow but it hasn't helped.

Here is my sender: (I have the uses-permission "android.permission.SEND_SMS" in my manifest)

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        }

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String msg = message.getText().toString();
                try {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage("5556", null, msg, null, null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("MYAPP", "fel: ", e);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

My receiving app have these parts:

Interface:

```
public interface SmsListener {
    void receivedSms(String message);
}
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) data.get("pdus");

        for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
            SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            String message = "From:" + smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress() + "Message: " + smsMessage.getMessageBody();
            smsListener.receivedSms(message);
            Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public static void bindSmsListener(SmsListener listener) {
        smsListener = listener;
    }
```

MainActivity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //adding view and checking permissions here

        SmsBroadcastReceiver.bindSmsListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void receivedSms(String message) {
        messageTextView.setText(message);
    }
```

Relevant parts of manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>

//added the receiver after the <activity for MainActivity
        <receiver
            android:name=".SmsBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter
                android:priority="100">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: how do you know the sms is actually being sent ? i'm not even sure how that would work on an emulator, who's paying for that sms to be sent ?